# enabling log in openSSH, Windows 2003 box

Tags: windows, openssh

I have 3 files inside OpenSSH\var\log, they are:
`lastlog
OpenSSHD.log
wtmp`
I changed the sshd_config file's 
LogLevel INFO

Then also I am not getting any logs, anywhere.

Can anybody help me to enable the log file.

Any help is appreciated.Thanks

Comment: This question should be on serverfault.com; search there as well, may already be answered.

Answer (score 4):

On Windows OpenSSH ports write to system event log, which you can view using Event Viewer. Files in /var/log are not used